# Who was Cersei's companion when she visited the witch?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Season 5, Episode 1:

When Cersei was a teenager she went to visit the witch in the woods to know her future.

Who was her friend who accompanied her to the woods? Why happened to her as she is never mentioned in the show again?

Comment: [When she was a teenager, Cersei Lannister went to visit Maggy at her hut in the woods, accompanied by Melara Hetherspoon](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Maggy). WRT "What happened to her as she is never mentioned in the show again?" Died? Stopped being friends? Moved away? Not everything needs an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the TV series, Cersei is accompanied by [Melara Hetherspoon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Melara_Hetherspoon), when visiting the witch (Maggy the Frog). In the books however, she is accompanied by 2 girls, Melara and Jeyne Farman.

Melara died very soon after the the visit to the witch. Part of Maggy's prophecy was that Melara would die. She's not mentioned anywhere else in the show because of this.

The link to Melara above gives some more details about what Melara wished for and how she died, didn't want to give any spoilers away by putting the information in clear text.

Comment: FYI You can use spoiler markdown `>! Spoiler text` to hide spoilers in your answers.